# What part of speech is "unless" in the following sentence?

Tags: grammaticality, prepositions, conjunctions

> Unless disciplined, a dog becomes a household pest.

Is the use of unless in this sentence correct? It sounds to my naive ear to be fine, but I always think of unless as a conjunction, which does not seem to be the case here. I looked up *unless* in an online dictionary and discovered that it can additionally be used as a preposition in the sense of "except for", but again that would not seem to apply to this sentence as disciplined is an adjective.  Since the sentence is taken from *Strunk and White* and sounds right to my ear, I am sure it is correct, so my main interest is to discover what the underlying construction is here.

Comment: Yes, it's correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the sentence,

> Unless disciplined, a dog becomes a household pest

*unless* is a conjunction*. This sentence is really a reduction of

> Unless it is disciplined, a dog becomes a household pest.

The conjunctional function becomes clearer upon a rearrangement of the clauses:

> A dog becomes a household pest, unless [it is] disciplined.

The most likely constructions a native speaker would use are the following:

> - A dog becomes a household pest, unless it is disciplined.
> - Unless it is disciplined, a dog becomes a household pest.
> - Unless a dog is disciplined, it becomes a household pest.
> - Unless disciplined, a dog becomes a household pest.

---

*I see how *unless* could be said to be used as a preposition:

> A dog becomes a household pest unless disciplined.

(No comma before *unless* and *disciplined* becomes an adjective.) I doubt this is formal usage, though. Before the independent clause, however, I would always take *unless* as a conjunction.

Comment: Thanks, I had never really noticed before that dependent clauses can leave out the subject and verb when preceding the independent clause.

Comment: "They didn't bother much at other times unless asked, and then they often had to think twice."  I found this sentence where it seems the dependent clause following the independent clause has the subject and verb understood. EDIT: This is probably the case where unless is a preposition.

Comment: @mcheema: Certainly! Great example. I would still consider *unless* used a conjunction there, with the subject and verb understood. I should edit that *unidiomatic* sentence in my answer. But honestly, I'm not sure where that *unless*-as-a-preposition came up... :)

Comment: I don't think it is helpful to call it a preposition in your last example. You *can* use "unless" as a preposition in at least some dialects: "It's not worth talking to anybody, unless Freddy". But I think that is functionally different from your "unless disciplined" because "disciplined" really is not a substantive here. "unless a disciplined one" would be a PP, but I don't find the suggestion convincing that "disciplined" stands for "a disciplined one" here.

Answer (score -1):

*Unless* means "if not"; hence, the word "not" should not be introduced in the clause beginning with "unless." For example:

> Unless you work hard, you will fail.